# How to use .a archive files in c++ eclipse project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, header, .a

i created a static library project in eclipse (helios)

the static library contained 3 .h header files and then build it to generate a lib.a file

now i want to use this archive file in a project so i set the path in the c++ settings linker loader
however now i have no idea how to include the 3 header files stored in the .a archive
on clicking the lib.a a file in the static lib project it shows a main.o object file
however this does not happen in the C++ project i intend to use it in

Comment: Select Project->properties from the main menu. Expand C++ General. Select Paths and Symbols. Select the Libraries tab. Click Add. Enter your library names. I believe you will need to leave off the prefix (lib) and the suffix (.a), so if all you have is lib.a, you might have a problem. You may also have to select the Library Paths tab and add paths to the libraries if they cannot be found just by name.

Comment: i named it as libASW_MODEL.a
and i did set the path
the library name and src folder
howevr how do i use the .h file inside this lib and include it

Comment: That's a damn good question. I've never added a .h file to a library. They usually travel along side the library with only the .o files from compiling the .cpp files implementing the .h files inside the library. Honestly, I don't think you are intended to put the header in the library. You can't link in a header.

Comment: thanks, i had no idea i couldn't do this.

is there a way that i can have a single lib or .o or any other file that contains a collection of header files which i need in multiple projects and just include that single file wherever i need to use the header files..

kinda new to this so i literally have no clue how to implement this

Comment: Again, never tried it. You can make a header that includes the other headers so you only need to include the one over-header to get all of the headers, as for bundling them into a container that a compiler can open and read... Friend, that is an excellent question unto itself.